# php switch statement using text box/drop down box

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement to make it so that when that specific word is typed into the text box it will display the available models of that car

for example

if the user entered "Volkswagen" it should echo "The available models are Beetle and Polo"

But for some reason it isnt working can anyone suggest to me why?

here is the code i have so far,

```
<form action="switch.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="cars" id="cars" />
       <input type="submit" /> 
<?php
$i = $_POST;
?>

<?php
switch ($i) {
    case "Volkswagen":
        echo "The available models are Beetle and Polo";
        break;
    case "Renault":
        echo "The Available models are Megane and Clio";
        break;
    case "Land Rover":
        echo "The Available models are Range Rover Sport and Defender";
        break;
}
?>
</form>
```

EDIT:

I am a bit stuck now i am trying to use this switch statement with a drop down box and not quite sure how i can make them work together if anyone can help me to make them work together that would be great

this is the code I have for the working switch and a working drop box.

```
<form action="">
<select name="cars">
<option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
<option value="Renault">Renault</option>
<option value="Land Rover">Land Rover</option>
</select>


<p>
<?php
switch($_POST['cars']) {
    case "Volkswagen":
        echo "The available models are Beetle and Polo";
        break;
    case "Renault":
        echo "The Available models are Megane and Clio";
        break; 
    case "Land Rover":
        echo "The Available models are Range Rover Sport and Defender";
        break;
}
?>
</p>
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is question formulated.

Comment: yeah i'll put a question in now and im sorry for causing so much trouble out of your busy patronising day i didnt realise i wasnt allowed to make a simple mistake like forgetting to add that part in, i hope i didnt cause too much trouble for you :)

Comment: Well, no clue what you're looking for, perhaps, you want to read how `$_POST` works? http://php.net/_POST

Comment: marc b explained what i needed to know and it now works so i am waiting until i can accept that as the answer

Comment: How is this not an update to [Text box limited to array contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398053/text-box-limited-to-array-contents) ?

Comment: because its a completely different task that i had to do that isnt using an array, the only similarity is that they both had a text box and it happens to be related to the same three cars mentioned in there

Comment: Just asking because it's not clear to me what you're asking there either.

Comment: And just for the log and your future questions: *"it isnt working"* isn't a valid error description. Please consult the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/help Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array. It is **NOT** something you can compare against strings. PHP will convert the array to the literal word `Array`. Since you don't have a case with that word, you get no matches at all.

Form values are submitted as elements of the $_POST array. You should be doing

```
switch($_POST['cars']) {
   ...
}
```

instead